# private members are not inherited. then how getters and setters able to access private fields in subClass?

Tags: java, oop, private-members

i have read from almost every source that private members are not inherited. Then how getters and setters of these private fields able to access private fields in subClass?

here is my code which is working fine.

```
class First{
private String first;
public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
 }
}


public class PrivateFieldTestingUsingGettersAndSetters extends First{
private String second;
public String getSecond() {
    return second;
}
public void setSecond(String second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    PrivateFieldTestingUsingGettersAndSetters ob1=new PrivateFieldTestingUsingGettersAndSetters();
    ob1.setFirst("first");
    ob1.setSecond("second");
    System.out.println(ob1.getFirst());
    System.out.println(ob1.getSecond());
  }
}
```

Output is:
first
second

Comment: Public getter's and setters are the window into your class's soul. They are inherited and have access to the private data. It is not a direct access though as you can either a) not define them or b) change how the values are accessed via them.

Comment: they are accessible from everywhere else, not only from inheriting class. if there was no way to call methods that uses private members encapsulation was pointless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write code this way, your `PrivateFieldTestingUsingGettersAndSetters` is *not* accessing its `First` parent's *private* data members.

It *is* calling *public* methods on parent `First` that have access to its private data members.  The parent class always has access to its state.

If you change `private` to `protected` in `First` for class members, it means that classes that extend First can have full access without getters or setters.  Classes that don't inherit from `First` do not have access to `protected` members.

If you don't supply setters in `First`, and make `First` members `private final`, it makes `First` *immutable*.  (That's very good for thread safety.)